# NPM-Scripts (in package.json) doesn't use the node_modules/.bin directory

Tags: json, npm, webstorm, package.json, npm-scripts

I have some scripts in the package.json file:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "webpack --config webpack.config.prod.js --progress",
    "dev": "webpack-dev-server --hot --config webpack.config.dev.js",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
    }
```

I installed the *devDependencies* in the package.json file (running the package.json in WebStorm) and npm created the `./node_modules/.bin/` directory with the needed binaries successfully.

### Issue

The problem is, when I run `npm run dev` to start the webpack server:

> sh: webpack-dev-server: command not found

### First Solution

I can solve this problem by giving the exact path to the `.bin` folder like this:

```
"dev": "./node_modules/.bin/webpack-dev-server --hot --config webpack.config.dev.js"
```

### Second Solution

I find another solution by adding the `.bin` to the global environment *PATH*:

```
export PATH="$PATH:./node_modules/.bin"
```

### Question

I can't use the first solution, because I don't work alone in this project and they don't have problems. Furthermore I read, that this should be work by itself (npm).

Second solution: I don't want to add the project packages (binaries) to my global PATH environment.

> It could be, that npm adds the `.bin` folder to the environment path automatically, normally.

I want to understand what is happing (why does it works for others automatically and not for me?)

Thanks for reading and helping, I think I'm not alone with this :).

Comment: yes, normally `.bin` is appended to the `$PATH` automatically by npm, and this works in WebStorm as well... Please make sure that *include system environment variables* is enabled in your *NPM* run configuration, *Environment* field. and (though it shouldn't normally be required), try enabling *Add the 'node_modules/.bin' from the project root to %PATH%* in **Settings | Tools | Terminal**

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I solved my problem. I edited my answer.

Comment: @bilal32 *" I solved my problem. I edited my answer."* I see no answer -- only a question. If you have solved your issue, try posting an actual answer (not sure if user with just 1 reputation can answer own questions though).

Comment: @LazyOne Thanks for you hint. I edited the question again and posted my solution as a answer.

Comment: @LazyOne Do you have any idea why I got a -1 on the question?

Comment: @bilal32 Your question is good (actual question, description and formatting). My only guess -- the same reason as I have stated in a comment. Otherwise -- maybe somebody simply did not like your explanation for whatever reason (was too simple/too obvious for him etc; there is no obligation to add reasoning: anyone with enough rep can downvote). Sometimes it could be a miss-click as well, but it can be easily fixed straight away if person notice it.

Answer (score 3):

## Final solution

I had a ":" at my path to the *./node_modules/.bin, but the ":" is used as a separator for the PATH environment (to separate the different paths to the binary directories). Therefore the shell never reached the *./node_modules/.bin* directory, because the path was like this:

> /Path/to/the/Project_19:20/node_modules/.bin

### **Never use a "/" in your file/folder names!**

":" occurred cause of a slash in the folder name.